# What are the chances that the battle minigame will be a 50-coin-per-player battle?

Tags: mario-party-8

I've played *a lot* of Mario Party 8, and I can't seem to ever remember having experienced the battle mini game being for more than 20 coins per player (and usually it's 10 per player).

Does anyone know what the chances are for a 50-coin-per-player battle (and maybe the others as well)?

Answer (score 4):

In Mario Party 8, the game always shows 50 as if you can bet that high. But in my many tests and conclusions, 50 was never able to be placed as a battle minigame bet. The developers seemed to have put it in there to troll some players (most likely younger kids) into thinking you could bet 50 in a battle minigame. The normal coin counts in battle minigames are between 10-20 and have no effect because of the player's or computers' coin counts.

Answer (score -1):

I think it has something to do with the amount of coins each player has. Generally, the game will not set a coin count that is 5-15 coins higher than the LOWEST players coin count. If you were to get all 4 players to the battle minigame with say, 120 coins, you might get the 50.